# Restrict level in busybox's tree command

Tags: busybox

The latest busybox ([1.36.0](https://busybox.net/news.html)) includes a `tree` command. But the command [docs](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) don't yet cover it.

How do I restrict it to a certain level, as I could typically do in bash with `tree L 2`?

I am unsure how to inspect the code to determine what switches it offers.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/tree.c#L124) and [tests](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/testsuite/tree.tests), it seems that busybox `tree` expects every argument to be a path. If there's no argument, it simply displays the current folder.

```
if (!argv[1])
    *argv-- = (char*)".";

// list directories given as command line arguments
while (*(++argv))
    tree_print(count, *argv, prefix_buf);
```

There's a TODO [comment](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/tree.c#L66), though:

> //TODO: when -l is implemented, use stat, not lstat, if -l

So it might expect more arguments in the future. You could try to contact the author, whose email address is listed at the top of the source code.

In the meantime, you could try to find a regex to ignore the lines which start with too many symbols:

```
> tree / | grep -Ev "^\W{20}"
...
│   ├── vmallocinfo
│   ├── vmstat
│   └── zoneinfo
├── root
├── sys
│   ├── block
│   ├── bus
│   ├── class
│   ├── dev
│   ├── devices
│   ├── firmware
│   ├── fs
│   ├── hypervisor
│   ├── kernel
│   ├── module
│   └── power
├── tmp
│   └── myvolume
├── usr
│   ├── bin
│   └── sbin
└── var
    ├── spool
    └── www
```

The unicode characters make it harder to count, though.